# In Aspnet.Core, can we change port number?

Tags: c#, .net-core, port, webapi, kestrel-http-server

I work on aspnet core web api project. I will publish this project to remote server. When Kestrel is running, default port is 5000 or anythink like this.

I want to change this port to 80 or 8080. Can I do that?

When I try to change from launchSettings, I get this error:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Failed to bind to address http://localhost:80.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be because you already have another web server running on your system (e.g. IIS) that is already binding to port 80.

You can check with this powershell command:

`Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess`

This command will show you what process is listening on port 80. If nothing is listening, it will return an error.